# Increment list index if condition

Tags: python, list, iteration

While iterating though all the elements in a list, I want to skip the succeeding two elements when a particular element is encountered, something like:

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
for index, element in enumerate(l1):
    if element == "b":
        index = index + 2
    else:
        print(index, element)

0 a
2 c
3 d
4 e
5 f
```

Comment: You practically solved it yourself with that pseudocode. @hancho has the answer.

Comment: Mark's is the more holistic answer. Using `next(iterator, None)` to skip a result in an iterator is very idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the index isn't going to work because it's created by the enumerate iterator. You could call `next()` on the iterator yourself:

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

iter  = enumerate(l1)
for index, element in iter:
    if element == "b":
        next(iter, None) # None avoids error if b is at the end
    else:
        print(index, element)
```

> 0 a
>   3 d
>   4 e
>   5 f

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
index = 0
while index < len(l1):
    if l1[index] == "b":
        index += 2
    else:
        print(index, l1[index])
        index += 1


0 a
3 d
4 e
5 f
```

Could use a while loop. `index += 1` in the if if you want 2 c